# Now that the "Return to question" link was removed, can we have a "original" question view while answering?

Tags: feature-request, markdown-preview

**Summary:**

Let me see the original question while answering.

**Long version:**

This is my pattern:

- Click on "answer"
- Open the original question in a new tab by clicking on "Return to original question" ( now gone )
- Switch back and forward to see if I'm missing something.

It is important to me to look several times at the question. I don't want to write a good answer and get downvoted only because the OP said:

```
Foo
```

and I typed:

```
Bar
```

and have comments and downvotes saying *"He said Foo not Bar"* and deviate the attention from the answer to the small mistakes I may have committed ( enough is to take care of the spelling already )

I would like to have ( honestly,  I don't really have a clue of "how"  ) a view of the original question while answering.

It was already a hassle having to switch between tabs, but now the link is gone, a just a couple of click harder  now I have to:

- click back
- dismiss whatever I might have written
- open the "answer" in a new tab
- and made a lot of mistakes because the question is now at my left and not at my right where it was.

phew!

Having this view, will allow me ( us ) to give better answers, and to use the system in a more "humane" way.

Related: [what-happened-to-the-return-to-answer-link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/what-happened-to-the-return-to-answer-link)

Comment: Though I also would like that link back, I wonder where you need to *Click on "answer"* ? I miss that link while editing *existing* answers or question, but to answer, I just start typing on the bottom of the page? (See workarounds at the related question you mentioned.)

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, please do that. If, as stated in the related question, the idea is to prevent quoting, then have the original question appear in a non copyable portion of the page.

I tend to think that if quoting is as much a temptation as Joel says, we would see that much amount of quoting already, regardless of how the site works now. And I don't see questions quoted, at all!

Comment: The quoting thing doesn't make any sense. I fail to see what might be bad about quoting and I certainly don't see much quoting on any of the trilogy sites.