# New way to edit bug -- Where are the previous edits?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, edits, inline-editor

I was just on this question: [How do I include an IF statement in this MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651716/how-do-i-include-an-if-statement-in-this-mysql-query) and I saw that it had been edited.

I wanted to see what the previous version was, so as I used to do, I clicked on `Edit`.

There used to be a dropdown in the title area with the previous revisions.  That is **no longer there**; is this a bug or is this the current implementation of the edit, where one **cannot** see the previous revisions (which could be useful to the historical context of a question)?

---

**Update**

Even on my own question: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) I cannot see the previous versions when I click edit.

This needs to be resolved.

---

**Update #2**

If you follow what @M.Tibbits says in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits/98133#98133) and if you click on `edit` instead of `source` you get the old implementation with the dropdown to switch between edits.

Why do we have to do some random convoluted steps to get to the old edit implementation?

Answer (score 6):

> Why do we have to do some random convoluted steps to get to the old
>   edit implementation?

The UI is optimized for the **most** common usage. Usually when editing you do not need the dropdown, if we add it the UI will be much more cluttered and confusing.

Similarly, editing tips are missing from the inline edit stuff. For the rare cases you need the extra context, you still have the history link and the ability to access the old UI with <kbd>Ctrl click</kbd>.

Keep in mind, the drop down was never intended to be a "history browser" the intention was to allow you to see you are editing an old revision.

We do not intend to have 100% parity with the full edit UI. I do not think that paralyzing users with too many extra options is a valid solution to your edge case.

Now, if most of the time people needed access to this drop down, or even 10% of the time, something may be justified. But that is not the case.

Comment: do you have a count of how many times people actually use the drop-down on the edit screen? I have used it quite a lot, and I am sure others have as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can still get to that option when you Ctrl-click the Edit link which will bring up the old version of the editor.

There the page will be replete with all its glory of revision drop downs, How to Edit box and clutter-free vision.

Comment: hmmm @random - why add on an extra unnecessary step, especially if I still want to edit inline? (ctrl-click takes you to a new page)

Answer (score 2):

If you click on edited [4 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6651716/revisions) it will take you to the revision history.

**Update:** If, after clicking on the revision history, you click on *source*:

[image]

You can then cut and paste the source you want to edit, *into the edit window* to work from any of the revisions.

Comment: yes, but it was much much easier when you can toggle to a previous edit on the edit screen and change things from there.

Comment: @re your update -- that still does nothing because it loses the ease of being on **one** page and seeing all of the edits on a toggle. **ALSO** it involves copying and pasting full questions!! why on earth would you want to do that when you have a few minor edits?