# Missing "revisions" drop-down menu in in-line edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, inline-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New way to edit bug — Where are the previous edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits)

We had "Revisions" drop-down menu where we could see & select edits we want to see/return post to.

There was for example

- genesis - added 32 characters to body
- someone - changed title

Why was it deleted in in-line edit?