# Add revision tab to edit interface

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New way to edit bug — Where are the previous edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits)

[image: Screenshot]

This tab available on edit page and It is very convenient for me.
But it is unavailable for me when I get edit interface since I get edit privilege.

Is it possible to add this tab to edit interface to users with this privilage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to inline editing. Well, there are a couple of other ways to get to the revisions for a post:

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> when clicking on the edit link (or middle click using your mouse wheel) to open the full-page edit interface, which has the revisions drop-down.
2. Click the date on the edit information to get to the revisions page, which also has edit and rollback (if you are the question owner or a mod) links.

   [image]

Comment: 1. yes, Also i can cleeck mouse wheel, but it's not so comfortable. 2. Will try to use it, thanks

Comment: Timestamp link is great!