# Is it possible to rollback my posts?

Tags: support, edits, posts

Lately I have noticed that I can't rollback a changes that was done to my post? Where did it go?

Comment: You still can, using either the method Siva described or by control-clicking on the "edit" link (or otherwise forcing it to open in a new window or tab). The problem is that the new inline editor was rolled out on all the SE sites for everyone with full editing privileges (which means you with 18k+ rep on SO), and it doesn't sport the revisions drop-down. You have to visit the full edit page to see that. More info is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the time stamp that appears on the post you edited.

[image: Timestamp]

Against the edit that you made, you will find the rollback link.

[image: Rollback]

Comment: I found no rollback link, and thanks for specifying the correct word...

Comment: Yeah, I see it now... didn't click on the editor but on edit before...