# Please correct the tool tip message on edit link in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, edits, tooltips

Based on this post [New way to edit bug -- Where are the previous edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits), the revisions drop down has been removed from the post edit link.

If I understand this correctly, this change has been implemented only in Stack Overflow because I can still see the Revision drop down on Meta and English website when I click the `edit` link of the post.

So the change is that if I click on the `edit` link on a post.

[image: edit]

The revision drop down that used to be above the Title will not be available any more.

[image: Revision]

That is my understanding of the change. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Could you please fix the tool tip text of the edit link? It still shows `edit this post, or roll it back to a previous version.` The roll back option is no longer available.

Please replace edit link tool tip with the text `edit this post`

[image: Edit this post]

**UPDATE:** Based on this post [Why there is inconsistency on edit functionality between Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101617/why-there-is-inconsistency-on-edit-functionality-between-stack-exchange-sites), it seems that I won't see the revision drop down when I click edit link if I have more than 2000 reputation points. So, I am little confused at this point.

Nevertheless, in my opinion I believe that tool tip should display the correct message based on what I can do at that moment.

Comment: The tooltip is still accurate, though. The way you roll back to a previous version is by control-clicking the link (or otherwise ensuring that it opens in a new window/tab). That will show the full editor, rather than the inline editor, including the revisions drop-down.

Comment: @Cody: Is that how it is supposed to work? I didn't realize that the link worked differently when I clicked it while holding the `Ctrl` key. It is kind of misleading to me. May be it is already mentioned somewhere in one of the posts.

Comment: It works differently because it opens in a new window/tab, which means that it can't open the inline editor. Yes, it's discussed in [waffles' answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits).

Comment: Well, there is still an argument for improving the tooltip... I'm just pointing out the current state of affairs.

Comment: @Cody: I will leave the question here to see if any devs respond to this.

Comment: That's up to you. My point is just that my comment wasn't saying "this is a bad question" or "we shouldn't change the tooltip". Sometimes people seem to interpret what I say that way, and I'm not sure why. Just trying to provide a little background info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed to

> revise and improve this post