# Why there is inconsistency on edit functionality between Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New way to edit bug — Where are the previous edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits)

This question is related to the post [Please correct the tool tip message on edit link in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101615/please-correct-the-tool-tip-message-on-edit-link-in-stack-overflow).

When I click on the edit link on a post, this is what I see on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overvflow and English Stack Exchange.

Stack Overflow does not show the revision drop down but Meta and English Stack Exchange does.

As the title says, why there is inconsistency on edit functionality between Stack Exchange sites?

**`Stack Overflow`**:

[image: SO]

**`Meta Stack Overflow`**:

[image: MSO]

**`English Stack Exchange`**:

[image: English]

Comment: The differences here are because you don't have over 2000 on all your accounts

Comment: @random: Thanks. Now, that makes sense. I spent a day reading the privileges. I have to spend more time understanding them correctly.

Comment: [Who is that handsome devil](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4MCw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inconsistency comes from whether or not you have normal editing privileges on the site. When you don't, the edit link is missing the `.edit-post` class, which causes the inline editing code not to be hooked up. I'm not sure whether or not that's intentional.

Comment: I have more rep points on Stack Overflow than the other two sites. So, I should see the revision drop down on the SO. Isn't it? This link mentions that the change on SO is intentional. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits I couldn't find other post that talks about this change. Still searching...

Comment: No, because the inline editor doesn't have the drop-down, and is working correctly for you on SO. On the other sites you're actually being taken to the normal edit page which does have the revisions drop-down (like if you opened the edit link in a new tab on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Thanks Tim. Answer provided by @random shows that I need to read the privileges section one more time and understand it properly.