# History support with inline edit (questions)

Tags: feature-request, inline-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slick new inline Q&A editing needs to set browser history or not look like a page change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98110/slick-new-inline-qa-editing-needs-to-set-browser-history-or-not-look-like-a-page)

When I click the `edit` below a question (or an answer) I'm not taken to `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/XXX/edit`. Instead, an inline editor replaces the question body and tags. This is all fine and well.

*But*, and this is the feature request, **would it be possible for the state change to affect the `#hash` value** of the page, e.g., `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/XXX/#edit-question`?

I often find myself clicking `edit` whenever a question seems incomplete (I'm looking at the MarkDown to see if the OP unintentionally wrote raw HTML or the like.) After having ascertained that I indeed *did* see the entire question body I'm in the habit of pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, thus *going back to the question listing* instead of just *leaving the edit state*.

**tl;dr**
While inline editing is a *state* I confuse it with a *relocation*. Therefore, I oftentimes find myself trying to leave the state by going back in (the unaffected) history of my UA. Feature request: let the edit state manipulate the `#hash` value of the page, thus supporting history without breaking the current behavior.

Comment: @random Yup, my search on `inline edit` seems a little insufficient :)