# No cancel option when editing a nomination

Tags: feature-request, edits, election, nominations

I recently tried to edit my nomination in Travel.SE and when editing I found that there was no cancel button in case I decided not to save my changes. (see the screenshot below)

[image]

Please add a cancel button next to Save edits option just like the one present while editing answers and questions.

Comment: there is a history of not having a [cancel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32277/158100) button...

Comment: This is no longer an issue since the revamp of the election UI: see [Moderator Elections: new questionnaire UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362933/moderator-elections-new-questionnaire-ui).