# Is there no path back to the question from the edit page?

Tags: feature-request, questions, edits, navigation

I went to edit my question, and got put into a revision editing list somehow, and I see that someone has edited it since I started, but there's no link back that I can find. Would it be possible to add one?

Comment: Does the `<-` button in the upper-left corner of the browser not count?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Now that the "Return to question" link was removed,  can we have a "original" question view while answering?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27940/now-that-the-return-to-question-link-was-removed-can-we-have-a-original-que) or [What happened to the “Return to answer” link?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/what-happened-to-the-return-to-answer-link)

Comment: Or Crtl/Cmd-click that Back button, to have most browsers open the previous page in a new tab or window.

Comment: @James: No, because almost every time I want to reopen the question, it's to double-check something in the middle of editing, and therefore I want it in a new tab.  The back button does not help.

Comment: Then, @Aarobot, what about that very same Back button while holding down Ctrl or Cmd, like I commented? (Middle-click might do the same trick.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a pita, I agree.  Pasting the URL back minus "edit" produces "Page not found".  Leverage the tabbed browsing feature that your browser supports.  Edit in another tab so you've always got a source tab to get back to the question.

It's a problem in general, the envelope is another example.  Jeff & co work on "check what's going on" once a day, maybe a couple of times a day.  Not quite compatible with the 9 minutes that a question can survive on the front page.  We might not have done a great job explaining how we use the site.