# Show comments when editing answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, edits

More than once I have been in a situation when a proper response to a comment just doesn't fit within the 600 character limit & the better approach is to edit the answer.

At times like these, being able to see the comment thread would be a real benefit.  When a comment addresses multiple issues, I typically find that I address part of the answer, save, compare the comment to the current state of my answer, then repeat the process until I'm done.

I can open the edit page in a new tab, but frankly I usually never think about this until I've been editing & I realize I want to reread the comment.  Sometimes this happens on questions too, but less often for me & I see that question has [already been asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form).

Comment: Even if you did think to open it up later: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/what-happened-to-the-return-to-answer-link

Comment: Actually This -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12845/greasemonkey-script-to-show-question-when-editing-answers post is pretty much what I need, but I would miss the preview.

Comment: Not really related, but would be helpful if this is implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40893/add-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-the-original-question-pane-on-the-answer-edit-page

Comment: @yoda - See my addition - you can always use the linked question title above the edit box to open the page in a new tab/window. Not perfect, but a start ;)

Comment: When this was a problem, I used to open a second copy of the question in another tab, and switch between the two tabs.

Answer (score 6):

An extra with the [new inline editing feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/faster-edits-with-inline-editing/) is that comments on the post, be it question or answer, remain when you kick into the inline edit mode.

Not only are comments on the post visible, but all the comments on that page are.

There, laying in wait, ready for the editor to pluck its collective juices and squeeze some more information into an answer, or clarity into the question.

Comment: I've noticed that already - very nice.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's only for users with 2k rep at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I often right-click on the `edit` link and open it in a new tab or window. That way I can see the complete original answer, the comments, the original question, and any other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as we now have the original question visible when editing an answer, it would be great to have the comments to the answer visible - that's usually why I am editing my own answers anyway - to provide additional context to the answer based on the OP's comments to my answer

It's not that my response might be more than 600 characters more that the response needs to be properly formatted, with more than "inline" code - the lack of support for paragraph breaks in comments means I rarely use them for responding to comments.

**Edit to add**

If it wasn't the case when the question was asked originally, when editing an answer now you can use the linked Question title to take you back to the original page - either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click, or right-click|Open in new window/tab.

Comment: @yoda, my answer presents a workaround that to me negates the need for the requested feature. Comments are hardly ever the only thing I need to refer to on the original page.