# Add a vertical scrollbar to the original question pane on the answer edit page

Tags: feature-request, answers, edits

Displaying the question right on the answer edit page is great, and I'm happy this was added.

However, I've run into a problem a couple of times. If the question is long, particularly with a snippet of code, currently you have to drag-expand the question pane all the way to the relevant section, and then scroll the browser window up and down between the answer input box and the question pane.

It would be nice to have a vertical scrollbar on the question pane in addition to the resizing capability (so it's just like the text box I'm typing in right now). This would eliminate having to scroll back and forth, which would make it much less frustrating to answer those questions.

---

[Original feature request for the display of the original question on the answer edit page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form)