# Inline Editing for Stack Exchange Sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, ajax, inline-editor

We have inline comment editing, inline editing of questions on Area 51, and inline re-tagging.

Can we please have inline Question and Answer editing on the Stack Exchange sites?

This has been implemented using a GreaseMonkey Script.  Try it out yourself.  It's old, so I'm not sure if it will still work:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/greasemonkey-script-to-edit-questions-answers-inline

Comment: `Please don't link to the Grease Monkey script that allows this.` => Why? Some people may be interested in it, such as me.

Comment: @Kop, I meant that it shouldn't be linked to as an answer to this question.  I don't know where it is, otherwise I'd link to it for you.

Comment: Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/greasemonkey-script-to-edit-questions-answers-inline

Comment: @Null, thanks for adding a bounty!  I'm not sure why this hasn't received any attention from any of the staff yet.

Comment: This is marked as completed, even though the functionality is available only to a relatively small set of users. Does that mean it will never be enabled for us lowlifes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This was a major PITA, good [old WMD](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/) had a lot of logic that only allowed 1 editor in a page.

With inline editing we need to have the ability to show 2 editors or we are stuck moving editors around and similar nasty hacks. The change involved touching 40 or so stylesheets.

This is now **enabled network wide** to people with the [editing privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).

<sub>It is not enabled for anonymous users or low rep users editing their own posts.</sub>

[image]

Comment: Oh, good - Ctrl+click lets me use the normal one!

Comment: Still no comments under the answer :(

Comment: @yoda ... please post a question on that ... I want to add it but its a fair refactor away

Comment: @waffles: There's been a [long standing feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29251/show-comments-when-editing-answers) (which is almost two years old now!) and I also placed a small bounty on it recently to bring attention to the request, but all I got was an answer telling me to open two tabs... like I didn't know that already! Anyway, good to hear that you're interested in it/considering it :)

Comment: @waffles: One problem I see is that when editing an answer *only* the answer is updated, but I won't be able to see other answers or even comments on my answer w/o refreshing the page - it might be just that this is "new" but it is irritating.

Comment: Hey @waffles could you tell me, how did you make animated gif as video-screening?

Comment: @genesis was not me, there is some sort of contrib on stackapps that does this

Comment: @waffles didn't find it :/ searched for "gif", "capture", "screen", "animation", ... Thank you, though