# Adding a link to post on Edit Page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits

Sometimes it happens that, by the time I am done with my editing someone else have done it already. Hence my change can't be committed. From there on, it's not possible to return to the question without pressing Back button on Browser. This is both inconvenient and erroneous as depending on browser settings, I may see the old unedited post. It would be helpful to have such a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until a link to return to question is added, or in case one is never added, here is an alternative to the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88816/adding-a-link-to-post-on-edit-page/88817#88817) given by [YOU](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541/you), along similar lines.

When you decide to edit a question, since the 'edit' option is a link, you can open it in a new tab itself via the middle mouse button or ctrl+click (as [YOU](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541/you) suggested for the back button), depending on whether you've changed browser tab options.

The benefit of this is that it will work in IE as well (IE < 7 doesn't support tabbing, however), since it relies on use of link characteristics, rather than browser supported back functionality.

When you are notified of an existing edit, you need only refresh the other tab to get the latest version of the question/answer you were editing, which also solves your problem with seeing an old version from the use of the back button.

**Update**

[In-line editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97824/inline-editing-of-questions-and-answers-on-meta-feedback-wanted) has been released following [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites).

If you are editing and you need to return to the question, you can simply click cancel or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to revert the edit - or use the existing question link at the top of every question (On the title).

Comment: Hmm neat alternative trick. Perhaps better than original accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

A new `cancel` link has been added to the edit page, to mimic the behaviour of the [inline-edit functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97824/inline-editing-of-questions-and-answers-on-meta-feedback-wanted). This link functions as per your request.

Of course, with the inline editing, you might just edit it *inline* and click `cancel` if there is a problem.

Comment: Does cancel refresh the content you were editing to include the new (now-modified-but-not-by-you) version, or does it just revert to what was on the page before you started editing?

Comment: @staticbeast interesting question; at the moment it is a flat revert, but we do a full refresh (of that post only) when you save, so it isn't beyond possibility to do that here too

Answer (score 3):

You could just click "Back" button while holding down Ctrl key also. (at least on Firefox and Google Chrome)

Comment: I somewhat often find myself at the "Oops, someone's already edited this." page; enough that I'm getting pretty tired of doing it this way.

Comment: I never knew about that @YOU.  Knowledge accepted.  Thanks!