# When editing on Meta are flags requesting 'status-something' considered useful?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

While trying to cleanup a few questions here, I've run across cases, for example:

- [Quick code format option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98426/quick-code-format-option)
- [Can we have a reply-to-this-comment arrow to click on, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/can-we-have-a-reply-to-this-comment-arrow-to-click-on-please)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102629/would-we-benefit-the-community-taking-chaos-edit-power

where I've considered flagging for moderator attention and noting that "This question should probably be marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)" (or similarly [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)).

**Question:**  Do you (moderators, et. al.), consider these flags useful?

**Background:** My flags have been marked valid in large part, but I'd prefer not to make noise/extra work for you.  I did a bit of searching for a policy, either unwritten or public, which defines when you want to tag such questions and came up empty. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These flags are helpful and useful in clearing out open feature requests or sating bug/support issues. If they weren't useful you'd have a couple of dings against your flag weight for invalid raises.

In cases where a question is open and may not be readily apparent that it's now under one of the status tags, leave an answer explaining the status quo or situation that warrants the tagging. If it's closed, you could still leave a comment.

Any one of the surly Meta moderators who spots the flag will come along in due time and supple-tag as such if it fits.