# Why isn't in-line editor for low-reputation users?

Tags: support, edits, privileges, inline-editor

I see no reason why it isn't allowed to in-line edit questions/answers for users below 2k. Is there some special reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the basic jist is that it's just a beta feature & they want to prevent the majority of users from having a tarnished experience -- forgive me if I misunderstand, I just figured that was @waffle's intent given [the large number of changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites/97821#97821).

Further, I guess it also makes sense that these are the users most likely to *use* the feature anyway.

Comment: Right, only people with edit privileges get the inline editor. I can't imagine why you'd want it otherwise, when the only posts you're editing are your own. Like a lot of the privileges (e.g., show vote counts), it's a gimmick they dole out as a treat to those of us who have earned reputation. Everyone knows by now that Jeff Atwood is really an online crack dealer.

Comment: @Cody, but the editing privilege is available to all users, only users with 2000+ reputation don't need peer reviewing.  So saying that a user with less than 2k reputation will only be editing their own questions is incorrect.

Comment: @staticbeast: Yes, but peer edits are necessarily rate limited, while the whole idea of inline editing is to make editing *faster*, just like the inline tag editor for 10k+ users. Those two goals are contradictory.

Comment: @Cody, Perhaps I have misunderstood your original comment? I agree that users below 2k reputation shouldn't have the inline editor (it acts as a bonus editing reward for hitting 2k). I was merely correcting the perception that users below 2k can only edit their own questions/answers: "`I can't imagine why you'd want it otherwise, when the only posts you're editing are your own.`"