# Can not see comments while editing question - is it annoying?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I'm editing my question in context of received comments and I feel a lack of such comments on the edit page. Well, the simplest case - to mention/quote some user without risk to misspell his name.

Workaround is straightforward - just use some neighbor tab with opened question.

This is **not** feature request. "Discussion" tag is for reason. I'm not really sure this is actually important, I just want to ask - does this bothers you from time to time?

Comment: TBH, I've never noticed. EDIT: I just tested it, and I can see comments when I edit a question.

Comment: Relevant linky: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites/97821#97821

Comment: @Peter Note there is a difference between inline editing and <2k editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's erked me a couple of times, but not to the point of needing to request a feature to include them on the edit page.

The only real annoyance I've had of it is when I'm editing an answer in response to questions.  But, as you say, just open the question in a new tab.  Problem solved.

Note: This should be solved now with [**inline editing**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites) for users with 2K+.

Comment: Users with less than 2k rep don't get the fancy inline editing functionality.

Comment: Ah, true...  Forgot about that bit.  Edited that in.

Comment: @squilman, nevertheless, you got a point. this solves problem even better than separate tab)

Comment: @Pop why is that, anyway?

Comment: I have no idea, @John. It was really annoying last week when I went on an editing spree on a site where I don't have 2k.

Comment: I think the reason for not having this for < 2k users is that one wants to discourage (a bit) edits by users which need approval, to not spam the edit queue. It could enabled for edits of own posts, though. (@John)