# Inline Edit - New Feature or Reputation Based?

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inline Editing for Stack Exchange Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites)

So I noticed that SO now allows me to edit questions and answers inline. Is this because I gained the reputation or is it a new feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both: it is [*kind of new*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites) (wow, time passes so fast, or, 'waits for no stack'), *and* you reached the [editing privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) (reputation of 2000) required to access it.