# A lower rep requirement to edit my posts inline

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, edits, privileges, inline-editor

The ability to edit my own answers and questions inline is a privilege given at [2k reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115994/inline-edit-new-feature-or-reputation-based) because it is the same privilege as [edit other's answers and questions without peers' review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

But it is difficult to achieve 2k reputation on low-trafic Stack Exchange sites.

Following [Dukeling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/206447/dukeling)'s [suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208852/give-me-a-blank-comment-box-when-i-am-editing-my-post-below-the-edit-summary#comment672381_208950), I request the creation of a new privilege, which is a variant of [edit privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) but restricted to my own answers (or questions), with a lower rep requirement (at 100 rep ?).

This request would make [easier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208852/give-me-a-blank-comment-box-when-i-am-editing-my-post-below-the-edit-summary#comment672381_208950) to [notify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208852/give-me-a-blank-comment-box-when-i-am-editing-my-post-below-the-edit-summary) commentators of my answer (or question) that I just made an Edit to answer their comments.

Comment: I thought it is on 1 rep. I think this would be right requirement.

Comment: What is inline editing?. I've never heard of that

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn: You already have it, if you have more than 2000 reputation.  Find one of your SO posts, and Ctrl-Click the Edit link, to see the editor that users under 2000 rep get.

Comment: @TheGrinch Oh so what we 2k+ rep users get when we click the edit link is called inline editing?

Comment: Yes, apparently.  [This is the original meta post.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 12):

Prior to achieving the required reputation, you get an extensive Editing Help system in the right sidebar, which is hidden once inline editing is enabled.  You can see it if you Ctrl-Click the Edit link (which will open the full-page editor instead).

The theory is that, once people get comfortable with the editor, you can jettison the help system and give them the (arguably more streamlined) inline editor.  I suspect that most people are comfortable with editing their own posts by the time they reach, say 500 rep.

Setting it at 100 rep would grant the privilege to new associated accounts (who probably already know how to edit their own posts by now).

Comment: It would be enough to recall in the inline editor that the full help will appear on the sidebar if edit is done with control-clicking edit.

Comment: The editor is the same across the network, right?? so why not make it the inline editor when I earned the edit privilege on *any* site in the network?

Answer (score 8):

Allowing folks who've learned to edit on one site to do so with less friction on other sites is a really good idea.

That said, the big show-stopper here is the lack of editing *guidance* on the inline editor. In particular, site-specific items such as MathJax help would never be seen by folks who garnered sufficient reputation on a site without them, if the association bonus sufficed to exempt editors from it.

We argued about this internally for a while, and eventually decided that it probably makes more sense to hold off until such a time as we're able to integrate more on-screen editing guidance into the inline editor.

Comment: Would you do anything special for the special sites?  MathJax and Balsamiq might require a refresher on the editor for those not familiar with it.  Or chess, or guitar thingy on that other SE site.

Comment: MathJax already has a place in the sidebar on the full edit page, @MichaelT. Other plugins probably *should*, but that was never done. This area of the site could obviously use some love.

Comment: @Shog9, it would be enough to recall in the inline editor that the full help will appear on the sidebar if control-clicking "edit".

Comment: @Shog9 : then set it to 200 rep when MathJax/chess are possible on a SE site, and to 100 rep for others SE sites.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, @user2987828. Not something we considered.

Comment: How many people who have high rep on one site have ever looked at the sidebar on other sites to see if there is anything special there though?  Despite having 3 dozen posts on mathjax enabled sites, I hadn't seen it before today; and had looked externally for help when I needed to use it.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no check for the reputation level in the inline editor, so I made a simple script which allows you to edit inline regardless of reputation (doesn't even require to be logged in), which [I already posted on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6216/inline-editor-regardless-of-rep).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Always Edit Inline
// @version      1.0
// @description  Adds an ability to lauch inline editor, which is used by  >2k users by default
// @author       nicael
// @include        *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @include        *://*stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @include        *://*serverfault.com/questions/*
// @include        *://*superuser.com/questions/*
// @include        *://*askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @include        *://*stackapps.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// @namespace    https://greasyfork.org/users/9713
// ==/UserScript==

$(".suggest-edit-post").removeClass("suggest-edit-post").addClass("edit-post");StackExchange.using("inlineEditing", function () {StackExchange.inlineEditing.init();});
```

[**Download!**](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8587-always-edit-inline/code)