# Show suggested tags when editing

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-tags

When authoring a meta question, the site will [suggest some tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-are-suggested-tags-chosen) to use based on the content of the question.

Can we enable that functionality when editing questions too?

Answer (score 2):

If you [control-click the "edit" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211246/a-lower-rep-requirement-to-edit-my-posts-inline#comment679017_211246) in the inline editor (to display the <2k non-inline editor), you will have suggestions of tags.

Comment: Are you referring to the inline tag editor available to 10k users? If so, that's useful to know, but I'm looking for this functionality for 2k+ users.

Comment: No, to the editor of the low rep users.