# Stack Overflow's edit interface not displaying the revision(s)

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list

In Meta, when we edit a post the revision will be displayed on the "Rev" field above 
"Title", as shown below:

> [image: Meta Edit]

But when I try to edit in Stack Overflow this feature is missing, i.e. it is not showing the revisions. See the image below.

> [image: SO Edit]

But when I right click on the edit and select "Open Link in New Tab"

> [image: New Tab Selection]

Then it shows the revision like:

> [image: SO edit with Revision]

Is this a bug or am I missing anything ?

**EDIT:**

I got the answer: it is not a bug, it is by design.
But is it necessary to have two different edit interface? What is the reason behind hiding the revision from 2K+ users when they use the normal (inline) edit interface?

Comment: @hims056: It happens to me for all the post, I checked many of them. Here I posted the images taken for this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736947/update-query-in-ios)

Comment: I always wondered what happened to that revisions dropdown...

Comment: Why the downvote ? It is happening to me, I'm not wondering why it is showing on meta and why not in SO. I'm wondered why it is behaving differently in direct editing and opening edit in new tab.

Comment: It was probably downvoted because it was originally tagged [bug], and someone said "this is not a bug, it's by design". [Downvotes work a bit differently on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). You didn't necessarily do anything wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks for the clarification, now I understand :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see on Stack Overflow is the [inline editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97821/209357) (`/posts/{id}/edit-inline`) which does not come with revisions. You do not have 2k on meta so you are shown with the standard editing (`/posts/{id}/edit`).

If you open the `edit` link in a context menu (or by disabling JavaScript), you will still see the standard editing page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is it necessary to add two kind of edit options, why the revision is hiding from 2k+ users ?

Comment: @MidhunMP You can always go to the post revisions by clicking the "last edited" link. And if you wish, you can also post a feature request here on meta for the revisions in inline editing.