# Include revision history in inline editing

Tags: feature-request, edits, revisions-list, inline-editor

If the user have reputation higher than 2K they are given the inline editor when editing questions and answers. However, the revisions are not shown in inline editing.

Inline editing for user with Rep > 2K :

> [image: user > 2K]

Standard editing for user with Rep < 2K :

> [image: user < 2K]

I think inline editing for 2K+ users should have the revision feature. Is it really necessary to remove the revisions option for 2K users? Because normally on Stack Overflow features and privileges increase with reputation, but this looks like an opposite case here.

It is very useful if 2K+ users also have the revision history when editing inline.

Comment: No, that has *nothing* to do with 2k. It has everything to do with editing past revisions. I am a 2K+ user, if I click on a past revision of a post I see the revisions list *just fine*. Try to edit [a past revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/189500/edit/ff65777b-71ef-4597-841a-61bcfbf70918) and see for yourself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Can you check this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189448/stack-overflows-edit-interface-not-displaying-the-revisions . Actually I thought it was a bug, but the answer clearly says it is built in functionality

Comment: Ah, you want to reword your post then and make it clear this has to do with inline editing versus non-inline editing, with perhaps a footnote that 2k+ editors are shown the inline editing variant. Your post is confusing right now.