# Editing a question on SO, I can see comments, answers, etc; on Unix&Linux, I can't — why?

Tags: discussion, edits

Since this seems to be a difference between sites on the Stack Exchange network, I guess MSE is the best place to ask.

I recently edited a question on the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235169/how-to-split-a-line-based-on-pattern/) site, and was surprised that I could not see the comments to the question or the answers while I was editing.  That was a nuisance; I was trying to copy information from a comment into the question, so I had to open another tab to see the original question and comments, and copy from that tab to the one where I was editing.  I don't recall ever seeing this on SO.

Apart from being different sites, I have more rep on SO than I do on U&L.

- Has anyone else encountered this behaviour?
- Is the difference expected?
- Is it a site difference, or a rep difference, or …?
- Which sites behave like SO and which like U&L?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/inline-editing-for-stack-exchange-sites/97821#97821 - you get inline editing with the edit  priv.

Comment: It's to do with your rep on the site in question.

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks.  That explains it — and why I'd not noticed it.

Comment: @Mat: I looked at that and I think it is a different issue.

Comment: It's trivial to enable inline editing using a [userscript](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/4a59be94921a48781e07), your edits still go through the review queues but you get the fancy editor.

Comment: It requires me to do more hacking of browser technology than I like; I'm not a web programmer, and I don't hack my browser or JavaScript for a living.  That's not to say it isn't valid or simple to achieve.  I've taken a quick look; there's a .js file.  I'm not sure how I'd install that in my browser.  (I've no problem whatsoever with my edits going through the review queue on sites where I don't have the rep to avoid it; that's what I'd expect.)

Comment: Beautiful script, @TinyGiant, really useful! . . . Jonathan, you need a browser extension to [handle userscripts](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info), Tampermonkey for Chrome or Greasemonkey for Firefox. With one of them in place, it's just a matter of visiting the `Raw` version of the file on Gist/GitHub and the extension will prompt for installation. There are all sort of [goodies at Stack Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) to tune SE sites.

Comment: @brasofilo if you visit http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js and search for ".edit-post" you'll see what I did, and what I mean by trivial. I just copied the function and applied it to the correct selector.

Comment: @TinyGiant: ahan, so, props to Oliver Caldwell, author of the EventEmitter used there ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design, on all of Stack Exchange sites.

Users without the [Edit Questions And Answers privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (typically <2k on graduates sites) are given a separate edit page when suggesting an edit.

You can reach this page directly even when logged in as high rep user, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/267714/edit and you can even CTRL+click the "edit" link to get this page.

When you gain the privilege to edit without review, you get the inline editing feature, hence you see all the comments.

Comment: OK.  It makes it harder to do some kinds of meaningful editing, but it isn't impossible — just a confounded nuisance.

Comment: True, and somehow I wasn't able to find a feature request asking to add the comments to that page - all the requests so far are only regarding the review, when reviewing the suggested edits. So, feel free to start one. :-)