# Weird shadow outline around posts when editing with `e` keyboard shortcut

Tags: bug, design, edits, keyboard-shortcuts

When editing a post using the <kbd>e</kbd> shortcut (but not the *Edit* link) on sites where you don't get taken to a separate `/edit` page to edit posts (I'm not sure what this feature is supposed to be called), a weird shadow appears around the edit UI:

[image: Editor with weird shadow on Code Golf SE]

This also occurs on other sites where the page-integrated editor thing is not enabled, but the shadow appears only very briefly before the page changes:

[image: Post with weird shadow on Meta SE]

Here's also what it looks like when using the dark mode on Stack Overflow:

[image: Post with weird shadow in dark mode on SO]

I'm using Firefox 90.0b6 on Linux. I have reproduced this with no extensions/userscripts enabled.

Comment: Think this background appears when the post gets focus, but should be cleared after couple of seconds. No JS errors in the console?

Comment: This feature is called inline editing (tag [[tag:inline-editor]])

Comment: @bobble Is there a help topic or a post offering specific guidance how to use it? Or it this just one of those things only available to the 3lite.

Comment: @ARogueAnt This is [only available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97821/) to those who have editing rights; 3k here and 1k on betas

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard It doesn't clear after a few seconds for me. And no, no errors in the console.

Comment: I know it doesn't clear for you, that's the bug, I was just giving direction. e.g. if you navigate to [this direct answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8483/152859), you should see the same "shadow outline" as you call it, around the answer, but in this case it vanish by itself. So the bug is that for some reason with keyboard shortcuts, whatever code used to clear the focus background is not executed.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the black box around a post when using the comment keyboard shortcut (c)?](/q/260191/289905) and [How is the below question highlighted with a background shade?](/q/275980/289905).

Comment: @bobble Erm, so the same editor I've been using for years then? Is there a corresponding out-line editor? I suspect I'm missing the point not being a programmer. I guess I'll just go back to the default and not worry bout what it's called.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I am actually using Firefox **90**.0b6 on Linux (different typo, but still a typo oops). It's a duplicate anyway, so I don't see why that's necessary

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. It is a usability problem that two different ways of invoking the same thing results in a different user experience (some technical reason does not justify this inconsistency).