# Show inline editor when clicking "Edit question" button in close notice if user has permission to use the inline editor

Tags: feature-request, post-notices, inline-editor

Yesterday, [a new "Edit question"/"Improve this question" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349479/when-is-the-edit-question-button-shown-on-close-notices) was added to post closure notices, to more easily provide access to the question editing form.

However, this new button will always open the separate post editor page (`/posts/[post ID]/edit`), and won't open the inline post editor even if the user has permission/privilege to use the inline editor (currently only 2k+ users, but there is [a question asking if it will be expanded to more users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276003/377214)).

This behavior is inconsistent: when clicking the usual "Edit" button below a post, it opens the inline editor, but when clicking the big "Edit question" button in the notice, it opens the separate editor page. I'd expect both buttons to do the same thing.

Can we please make the button open the inline editor when clicked, for users who have permission to use it, instead of always going to the separate editor page?

Comment: Why aren't these addressed?