# The in-review-queues edit layout is different from the normal (out-of-review-queues) edit layout on mobile. How can I always use the former?

Tags: support, review, edits, user-interface, full-site

#### Overview

I can't always be in front of a computer, so I sometimes use an Android/Apple phone (with Firefox browser) to use [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). There I have noticed that when I edit a post in the review-queues by selecting the edit option, I get the interface like this (cropped screenshot):

---

[image: mobile (full site) interface when pressing the "Edit" button in the review queues]

<sup><sub>[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH3BL.jpg) is a better screenshot.</sub></sup>

---

However, when I edit a post out of a review queue by clicking on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button below it, I get an interface like this (cropped screenshot):

[image: Editing interfaces out of review queues.]

I prefer the first interface, the in-review queues one, but I'm not able to use it unless or until I edit in a review queue.

Responsiveness is enabled (But I am not sure, but the responsiveness button shows the option "disable responsiveness", so it seems like responsiveness is enabled) and the desktop mode is not on in both cases.

How can I always get the first edit interface when I'm editing on my mobile?

When I turn on Desktop mode, (while editing normally) I get the same [interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV838.jpg). If I disable or re-enable responsiveness I get the same interface again.

I have [posted a question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19849/1460940) on [Meta Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com) addressing the same issue.

**Note**: Responsiveness is enabled in both cases and the desktop site is off. The issue is with the full site of [Ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). The same is with all the communities. Also, users with 2000 or above reputation do not get this type of User Interface. They get the inline editing interface.

Meta Stack Exchange (modified screenshot):
[image: MSE screenshot.]

Comment: 2k+ users have a different interface called the inline editor. For some reason it's not even mentioned on the privileges page. The idea of [extending it to everyone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276003/323179) was brought up but it never went anywhere.

Comment: With the inline editor, you can see/edit the other answers and also write an answer yourself while editing a question or answer. ([Example of editing a question without answers and the preview hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5yBo.png).) Everyone else's screenshots don't show what's below the post, so that's why it's not so obvious. (Also, a 2k+ user can get the other editor by opening the edit link in a new tab, but I don't know why anyone would prefer that. Don't know why the inline editor's not an option for everyone.)

Comment: This isn't a bug. As others have said in the comments, there are multiple different editors depending on your privilege levels. Some have not yet been made responsive, but that will likely happen within the next month as we work towards getting rid of the mobile views.

Comment: The part about the different footers is one change of the new responsive design. If you go below a certain resolution the footer items convert from vertical columns to horizontal rows. That works well for the footer since it makes better use of space and wraps better. Regarding the editor, as other commenters have already said, there are 2 different editors inline/normal and that part of the site has yet to be made responsive. It's a work in progress but it's getting better with every iteration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of *15th January; 2022*, **the editing user interface** (*for less than 2k rep users in the full-site version of Mobile Site*) **has been made responsive**. Now, the UI which is shown to users having less than 2k reputation is similar to the [inline editing interface.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374211/the-in-review-queues-edit-layout-is-different-from-the-normal-out-of-review-que#comment1247125_374211) Which means, now **[you'll no longer see the whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqrZvl.jpg)** *(as similar to the desktop view of the editing interface; whole page includes footer, sidebar, editing tips etc..)* **at once while editing any post**. The UX is *undoubtedly* good and similar to the Mobile Editing interface.

Screenshot (*[This question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405783/495805) has been used for the screenshot)*:

> [image: .]