# On the <2k edit page, can we please see the comments on our post?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, editor

I receive suggestions (in comments) to improve my own question. I start editing. I forget some of the suggestions, what should I do? I normally go back and forth until I finish editing. I can use two tabs but it'd be much more helpful to me if I could see the comments on the editing page.

This ability [was previously requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29251/show-comments-when-editing-answers), and was implemented for 2k+ users with their inline editor, but it wasn't implemented for <2k users for no apparent reason.

Can the comments please be added for <2k reputation users while editing our own posts or community wiki posts?

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. As a work-around although it's not really an ideal solution, have you tried having your question open in 2 tabs or separate browser windows, with you editing your question in one and checking the other one for new comments?

Answer (score 9):

This has been fixed! The comments have been added to the post edit page which is used by users with lower reputation. You can see the fix for yourself on the [edit page for this very question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/346561/edit)!

Thanks for reporting and definitely let us know if you run into any problems using this.

Comment: Just wondering, why not just [expand inline editing to all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276003/377214) while you're at it?