# Why was inline editing only ever implemented for users with editing privileges?

Tags: support, edits, inline-editor

This is not a duplicate of the following posts:

- [On the <2k edit page, can we please see the comments on our post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346561/on-the-2k-edit-page-can-we-please-see-the-comments-on-our-post) - that's a *feature request* asking to enable inline editing for <2k users; this is a support question
- [Will inline editing ever be rolled out to users with less than 2k rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276003/will-inline-editing-ever-be-rolled-out-to-users-with-less-than-2k-rep) - that question asks if there *will be* inline editing support for <2k users in the *future*; this question is asking about a *past* decision

Anyway, with that out of the way, let's get to the question.

Inline editing is a feature given to users with editing privileges, which allows them to edit a post inline with the rest of the post, allowing them to see other parts of the question page, such as comments and other answers. In my opinion, it's a useful feature for *all* users, as it allows them to see comments (improvement suggestions) on their posts while they edit them, which is not possible in the separate editor page.

When the feature was [originally announced](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/11/faster-edits-with-inline-editing/), it was only made available to users with editing privileges, but there was a plan to expand it to all users eventually:

> We’ve only opened up inline editing to editors (users with 2,000+ reputation) for now, but we might extend it to all users eventually.

It seems that sometime after the blog post was published, the team made the decision to not go through with their plan to expand inline editing to all users.

Why was the original decision made back then to not expand it to all users at that time? (I'm not asking what is the *current* reason, which may change since the recent feature request above to expand it has been marked as under review, but why it was *originally* decided back then to not expand it. Did it simply languish at that time, or was there some discussion long back about it with an outcome of not expanding it?)

Comment: Could be because users without full edit privileges may benefit from the [How to edit panel](https://i.imgur.com/B85UVFy.png) and the information it provides, though, a more official response would be nice.