# link to the question in edit mode

Tags: feature-request, edits, hyperlinks, usability

Hello, I asked a question, got a response and decided to update the question.

Being in edit mode, I decided to cite some info from the answers but I do not see any link to the question in view mode. And I even do not have an idea how to reach there in a couple of clicks. I remember that there was such a link before, because I used it.

Why is it gone? Is it a bug? Or does everyone remember exacly the answers and the names of those who answered now?

Comment: related (kind of the opposite): [Display the original question beneath the answer edit form](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/display-the-original-question-beneath-the-answer-edit-form). Seems like some other requests (e.g. [What happened to the “Return to answer” link?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/what-happened-to-the-return-to-answer-link)) have always only been made for answer-editing, not question editing.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my turning this into a feature-request, but this would certainly be useful

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: no objections. I thought the link had disappeared unintentionally =)

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: I have just realized that I used the link in answers (there is one there), and never in questions. Then it is certainly a feature request. I am sorry. But it would be usefull in questions as well )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I even do not have an idea how to reach there in a couple of clicks.

Workaround for the moment: Select all text in the question and copy. Click back button. Open the edit link in a new tab, select all and paste.

As Bobby points out, its even easier with Firefox: A middle-click on the back-button opens the question in a new tab.

Comment: In Firefox you can middle-click on the back button, so that it opens in a new tab.

Comment: @Bobby: Nice, i never noticed.

Comment: The same works in Chrome too.  If you don't have a middle mouse button, use Ctrl+Click.

Comment: This exacly I had to do, and I did not like it. Thanks to @Bobby for the tip.